# Join 3 lists initiating the join from the middle list

Tags: javascript, caml-query, caml

I need to join 3 Lists, but i have no access to the on-prem sharepoint to test my idea right now. So I hope anybody can tell me, if it's possible.

I have Lists A, B and C.
LookupFields are connected from List C -> B -> A. (one LookupField each)

I want to start the join from List B. I get list B with `web.get_lists().getByTitle("B");` via JavaScript.

So starting the join from list B, would something like this be possible?

```
<Joins>
 <Join Type='INNER' ListAlias='A_'>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name='LookupField_in_B' RefType='ID'/>
   <FieldRef List='A_' Name='ID'/>
  </Eq>
 </Join>

 <Join Type='INNER' ListAlias='C_'>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef List='C' Name='LookupField_from_C_to_B' RefType='ID'/>
   <FieldRef List='C_' Name='ID'/>
  </Eq>
 </Join>
</Joins>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much, although you would want to left outer join your tables.

Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975(v=office.14).aspx) MSDN article for reference.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. The join is only working when joining the lists from C -> B -> A. Not C <- B -> A.

Comment: Yes sorry, you would always want your primary table on the far left.